# getting "Stream Was Not Writable" while saving an XML document that I read via a stream from a zip file

Tags: c#, xml, stream, dotnetzip

I have a zip file that contains an xml file,
I'm Loading this xml file to an xml document without having to extract the file.
this is done via a stream.
after doing so, I'm modifying the inner text of some nodes.
The Problem is that I'm getting the previous mentioned exception after trying to save the stream, here's the code:

(I'm using **DotNetZip** here)

```
ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(zipPath); // the path is my desktop
foreach (ZipEntry entry in zipFile)
{
  if (entry.FileName == "myXML.xml")
  { 
    //creating the stream and loading the xml doc from the zip file:
    Stream stream = zipFile[entry.FileName].OpenReader();    
    XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(xReader);

    //changing the inner text of the doc nodes:
    xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Account/Name").InnerText = "VeXe";
    xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Account/Money").InnerText = "Million$";

    xDoc.Save(stream); // here's where I got the exception.
    break;
  }
}
```

I'm not a pro coder, but instead of `xDoc.Save(stream);` I noticed that it could also take a `XmlWriter` as a parameter, so I tried making an instance of the XmlWriter immediately after instantiating the XmlReader ..
I tried doing this: `xDoc.Save(XmlWriter)`
I got an exception saying something like: "Cannot Write After Reading"

how can I successfully save the xDoc ?

**ADDED:**
I had an idea of saving the xml file in some other place, like a temp folder or something 
then adding that saved file in the zip overwriting the old one, then deleting the xml file in the temp ..
but that's not what i want, I want to deal directly with the zip file, in and out, no third parties.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to write to the same Stream you've opened it with. You cannot do that.

Perhaps try something like this:

```
ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(zipPath); // the path is my desktop
foreach (ZipEntry entry in zipFile)
{
    if (entry.FileName == "myXML.xml")
    { 
        //creating the stream and loading the xml doc from the zip file:
        using (Stream stream = zipFile[entry.FileName].OpenReader()) {
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(xReader);
        }

        //changing the inner text of the doc nodes:
        xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Account/Name").InnerText = "VeXe";
        xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Account/Money").InnerText = "Million$";

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(pathToSaveTo)) {
            xDoc.Save(streamWriter); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added to my question that I want to deal directly with the zip file, I don't want to save the xml someplace else, then add it back to the zip file.

Comment: Either way, you need to close your reading stream before proceeding to open a writing stream.

Answer (score 0):

A quick [look at the docs](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/html/fefc7f88-eed1-4901-1061-1909c23f83aa.htm) leads me to believe that you should do it something like this:

```
using(ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(zipPath))
foreach (ZipEntry entry in zipFile)
{
  if (entry.FileName == "myXML.xml")
  { 
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    //creating the stream and loading the xml doc from the zip file:
    using(Stream stream = zipFile[entry.FileName].OpenReader())
    using(XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {    
        xDoc.Load(xReader);
    }
    //changing the inner text of the doc nodes:
    xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Account/Name").InnerText = "VeXe";
    xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Account/Money").InnerText = "Million$";

    using(var ms=new MemoryStream())
    using(var sw=new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        xDoc.Save(sw);
        sw.Flush();
        ms.Position=0;
        zipFile.UpdateEntry(entry.FileName,ms);
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's pure pedantry @JohnSaunders. It's a verbatim copy of OPs code except the saving part. You go the extra mile, find the docs, write some code and get rewarded by pedantry. I'll fix it, just for you. x

Comment: ...and another one that you didn't catch.

Comment: @spender I think UpdateItem has only 2 overloads, one of them takes one string which is "itemName" the other takes 2 strings, "itmeName" and "directoryPathInArchive". so there's no overload that takes a memory stream. that's why i got an error for that.

Comment: @VeXe : sorry, meant to use `UpdateEntry` (as per linked doc page)

Comment: @spender: didn't really work man, The xml in the zip is not getting changed ..
although when debugging I'm seeing that the contents of xDoc's nodes inner text is exactly the values that I assigned to them.
So I think there's some sort of problem with code snippet you added ..

Comment: @spender: I consistently downvote for this reason. People copy and paste our code, so even if it's from the bad code posted by the OP, you endanger the copypasters by not correcting the original code in your answer.

Comment: @VeXe : you did `zipFile.Save()` right? Here's a page of examples for you... update is last on the page... http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/Code%20Examples/CSharp.htm